# Render precompilled nunjucks (browserify+nunjucksify) with ampersand-view

Tags: nunjucks, ampersand.js

Trying to render `browserify+nunjucksify`-ed precompiled templates in a an `ampersand-view`.

This works as expectd:

```
var tpl = require('app1/template-1.nunj');
console.log(tpl.render({name: 'flemming', isDancing: 'perhaps'}))
```

This does not:

```
var MainView = View.extend({
    template: tpl.render,
    bindings: {
        'model.name': '[data-hook=name]'
    }
});
```

The error i get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dev' of undefined
```

AFAIK, this means that the `this` for the nunjucks is wrong. `Ampersand-view` sets itself as `this` for the rendering function, overshadowing what nunjucks expects `this` to be.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard this issue, I'm leaving just in case others have the same issue.

The problem is non-existent, as nunjucks needs to render the template before we set/pass it to the view. This way the first rendering will fill in all non-model (static) props, such as translations etc, and then the view handles all model-props.

...I think.